# Jquery SlideToggle() not working properly in iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios

I have the below code implementing SlideToggle of Jquery. It is working all other places except in iphone. In iphone, the element is visible and immediatly getting hidden in a flash

```
           jQuery('.toggle').click(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault(); 

                jQuery('#navigation').slideToggle(); 
                return !1 
            });
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but if you're so keen to save characters that you use `!1` instead of `false` why do you bother with the redundant `e.preventDefault();`?